# Как получить состояние кнопки мышки в mouseover?

Tags: javascript

Все предлагают запоминать состояние в событиях `mousedown`, `mouseup`.

Этот вариант не подходит.

Проблема в том, что мышку отпускают вне браузера, и события не отрабатывают.

`ДОБАВИЛ`

предлагают запоминать состояние мыши в событиях:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var isDown = false;   // Tracks status of mouse button

  $(document).mousedown(function() {
    isDown = true;
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    isDown = false;
  });

  $(".myDiv").mouseover(function(){
    if(isDown) {
       alert('!');
    }
  });
});
```

но если я:

- нажму мышку в браузере
- отпущу мышку за браузером
- вернусь в myDiv

`isDown` будет содержать не правильное значение, и `alert` сработает, т.к. `mouseup` не сработал

Comment: А как `javascript'у` _внутри_ браузера отследить события кнопок мыши _вне_ браузера?

Comment: @SLy_huh, я и предлагаю не отслеживать события вне браузера. А расчитывать ситуацию на момент возврата в браузер. Мне для этого нужно узнать состояние кнопки мыши на текущий момент.

Comment: В каком плане - не отрабатывают? Приведи хоть кусочек кода, или внеси побольше подробностей в проблему.

Comment: @SLy_huh, расширил вопрос

Comment: `$(document).mousedown(function(){ console.log(true) }).mouseup(function(){ console.log('false')})` - Зажимаю в окне, вывожу - отпускаю - в хроме отрабатывает отлично, оба события логгируются; мб я чего-то не понимаю конечно

Comment: @SLy_huh, да отработал, у меня висел на `body` видимо изза этого не срабатывал